# Delphi interface reference count mechanism

Tags: delphi

Indeed there is a lot of stuff online about this but more I read more confuse I am. I have written a component called `Combinatorics` that does some math probability stuff. The code is pretty short and easy because I don't want it to be complicated. I am doing a little preview here:

```
//Combinatorio.pas
type
 ICombinatorio = interface
  function getSoluzioni(): integer; //soluzioni means "Solutions"
  function getFormula(): string;
 end;

//ImplCombinatorio.pas
type

 TCombinazioni = class(TInterfacedObject, ICombinatorio)
  private
   n, k: integer;
   ripetizione: boolean;
   function fattoriale(const x: integer): integer;
  public
   constructor Create(const n, k: integer; const ripetizione: boolean);
   function getSoluzioni(): integer;
   function getFormula(): string;
 end;

 TDisposizioni = class(TInterfacedObject, ICombinatorio)
  private
   n, k: integer;
   ripetizione: boolean;
   function fattoriale(const x: integer): integer;
  public
   constructor Create(const n, k: integer; const ripetizione: boolean);
   function getSoluzioni(): integer;
   function getFormula(): string;
 end;

 TPermutazioni = class(TInterfacedObject, ICombinatorio)
  private
   n: integer;
   k: string;
   ripetizione: boolean;
   function fattoriale(const x: integer): integer;
  public
   constructor Create(const n: integer; const k: string; ripetizione: boolean);
   function getSoluzioni(): integer;
   function getFormula(): string;
 end;
```

You don't need to see how functions and procedures are implemented, it's not important for the question (and you can easily imagine what they do).

---

This is my first component ever, I have compiled and installed it and it works. However I cannot understand something.

```
unit TCombinatorio;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Combinatorio, ImplCombinatorio;

type
 cCombinatorio = (cNull = 0, cDisposition = 1, cPermutation = 2, cCombination = 3);

type
 TCombinatorics = class(TComponent)
 strict private
  { Private declarations }
  Fn, Fk: integer;
  FRep: boolean;
  FType: cCombinatorio;
  FEngine: ICombinatorio;
  procedure Update;
 public
  { Public declarations }
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  function getSolution: integer;
  function getFormula: string;
 published
  property n: integer read Fn write Fn;
  property k: integer read Fk write Fk;
  property kind: cCombinatorio read FType write FType default cNull;
  property repetitions: boolean read FRep write FRep;
end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
 RegisterComponents('RaffaeleComponents', [TCombinatorics]);
end;

{ TCombinatorics }

constructor TCombinatorics.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin

 inherited Create(AOwner);
 Fn := 0;
 Fk := 0;
 FType := cNull;
 repetitions := false;

end;

function TCombinatorics.getFormula: string;
begin
 Update;
 Result := FEngine.getFormula;
end;

function TCombinatorics.getSolution: integer;
begin
 Update;
 Result := FEngine.getSoluzioni;
end;

procedure TCombinatorics.Update;
begin

 case FType of
  cDisposition:
   FEngine := TDisposizioni.Create(n, k, repetitions);
  cPermutation:
   FEngine := TPermutazioni.Create(n, '', repetitions);
  cCombination:
   FEngine := TCombinazioni.Create(n, k, repetitions);
  cNull:
   raise Exception.Create('You have to select a type.');
 end;

end;

end.
```

Look at the `Update;` procedure. I have created that because when the user drops the component ( [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBVUJ.png) ) in the form he has to setup in the object inspector (or with the code somewhere) 3 important parameters required in the constructor.

Since `FEngine: ICombinatorio` I can assign to it a class (TCombinazioni, TDisposizioni or TPermutazioni) without try finally because there is the ref count mechanism. I am not sure if I have coded this properly. Suppose that:

1. The user selects `cDisposition` and does a calculation
2. The user selects `cDisposition` (different values) and does a calculation
3. The user selects `cPermutation` and does a calculation

I am always working on the `FEngine`. How does the ref count go to zero? Does it go to zero when the form (and the component) destroys? I hope I have explained well what I don't understand. The `FEngine` is a private variable and I assing to it at runtime different classes (calling the Create). Does the ref count go to 0 when the form destroys or when a new class is assigned?

I coded it like above because nick hodges did that in his book and I trust him of course but I'd like to know what I do.

Comment: You could simply add destructors to your interfaced objects and put  breakpoints to find out what happens.

Comment: I guess you are referring to the TEncryption example of "coding in delphi" ;) I have just checked the book, you should find the answer to your questions in the middle of the chapter when he talks about TInterfacedObject!

Comment: @Sertac I dont know what you are talking about sorry, I am learning now so I thought it was easier to ask

Comment: @Alberto yes chapter 2 of that book :) yes he explains well but I wasnt very sure about what I got from the chapter

Comment: @Raffaele Ok. You can try it now if you want to learn more. Put destructors in your interfaced objects (TCombinazioni , ...). They don't have to do anything more than to call the `inherited`. Then put breakpoints on the 'inherited' statements. Then select "use debug dcus" in "compiling" project options. And run the project. When the debugger stops examine the call stack.

Comment: @Sertac wow ok! I'll try it now thank you for the explaination

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the code that can be seen, the first time `Update` is called, a new implementor of `ICombinatorio` is created and assigned to `FEngine`; the reference count will be 1.  The following times that `Update` is called, another new instance of `ICombinatorio` implementor will be created (its reference count will be 1) and is assigned to `FEngine`.  The previous implementor instance that `FEngine` pointed to will have its reference count decremented; if it is zero, then it will be destroyed. (It probably will be based on your code sample).

Also, when the destructor of the component is called (when the owning Form is destroyed), the implicit instance clean-up code will set `FEngine` to nil, which will decrement the reference count (and, based on your sample, will be destroyed).

So, based on your code sample, I would expect your code will work properly; cleanly instanciating and destroying the `ICombinatorio` interfaced objects.

Comment: Aaaaah ok, so when I assing to FEngine a new instance the old one has a ref of 0 (so it's destroyed) and the new one goes to 1. I thought that the reference didn't go to 0 but has an overall sum. You say that it's 0-1-0-1-0-1... but I thought that it was like 0-1-2-3-4 and then 0 at the end (on destroy). Thank you

Comment: See `_IntfCopy` in system.pas for how it is implemented, and the comment there for reasoning.

Comment: @Raffaele: no, it does not go 0-1-0-1 etc... The more references to an interface exist, the higher the refcount. But in your example, the refcount of the interface (NOT: of the variable, don't confuse that) is 1. If another instance is assigned, then the refcount of that new instance is incremented, and the refcount of the instance that is being replaced is decremented. If, after the decrement, the refcount becomes 0, it will kill itself.If you had other variables referencing the instance, then it would be higher than 1, and decrementing would not make the refcount 0 and it would stay alive.